# Why is my website not displaying properly in internet explorer 8?

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility

my website does not display anything properly when viewed at with ie8. It looks good with chrome, safari, and firefox. It looks almost perfect with ie10, and I am unsure if ie9 would display it normally or not. I know other people have trouble with internet explorer. In most cases there should be a simple solution, so I am hoping if someone could view the source and see if there is anything missing that would make internet explorer not compatible with my website. You can view this page of my website and check it out to see if you can spot anything wrong. The link is this: http://a4um.com/fumSignup.php

Comment: I think you will need to be a little more specific about what is not displaying properly in ie8.  I did find a broken link and a span with typos in the source... don't know if that is what is causing the issue and if it is a php issue, rendering the wrong html server side.

Comment: '<span style="color:red";>!' and '<a href =class = "hide">' were the mistakes in the source that I found.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your page in internet explorer 8 and it is displayed very wrong, but after looking at your css file, I noticed some major syntax mistakes as well.  I am not sure of your experience level, and sometimes cross-browser display can get a little complicated but it looks like your css file needs some of the basics fixed first.  This section in particular:

**EDIT:** Also, nav is a html5 element which is only supported by IE9 and above.

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }
nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }

nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        position: relative;
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 0px 10px;
            color: #fff;
        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #4b545f;
            }
```